# Integration of a rotary encoder as input device (AOSP)

Tags: android, android-source

I'm trying to integrate a rotary encoder in Android. Even though device.type is set to rotaryEncoder in the device configuration file, there is a logcat entry that shows class 0x1000 instead of 0x400000. I've no idea what's wrong here. Expect the most stupid mistakes as I'm not really familiar with the AOSP.

input device configuration file:

```
rpi3:/ # cat /system/usr/idc/rotary_0.idc
device.type = rotaryEncoder
device.internal = 1
device.res = 1
device.scalingFactor = 1
```

key layout file:

```
rpi3:/ # cat /system/usr/keylayout/rotary_0.kl
axis 0x08 SCROLL
```

getevent -il

```
add device 1: /dev/input/event3
  bus:      0019
  vendor    0000
  product   0000
  version   0000
  name:     "rotary@0"
  location: ""
  id:       ""
  version:  1.0.1
  events:
    REL (0002): REL_WHEEL
  input props:
    <none>
```

dmesg:

```
[    3.544491] rotary-encoder rotary@0: gray
[    3.547289] input: rotary@0 as /devices/platform/rotary@0/input/input3
```

logcat:

```
01-17 20:55:47.439   469   515 I EventHub: New device: id=1, fd=83, path='/dev/input/event3', name='rotary@0', classes=0x1000, configuration='/system/usr/idc/rotary_0.idc', keyLayout='', keyCharacterMap='', builtinKeyboard=false, wakeMechanism=EPOLLWAKEUP, usingClockIoctl=true
```

Android version is 7.1.2

Comment: I am not familiar with your project, but have you checked out Android Things?

Comment: @dazza5000 Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to understand what's wrong here.

Comment: Yes sir. I wish I could help you, but am unfamiliar with this part of the android platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the HAL of Android 7.1 already supports this, the Android SDK doesn't for API Levels below 26. It therefore requires Android 8.0 in order to have non-directional scroll wheel support.